# How to add up sets of consecutive integers with good performance

Tags: vb.net, performance, linq

I've got an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` and want to add up each set of three consecutive integers, starting by the first one and ending by the last one minus two.

Example: My integers are `{0, 6, 2, 8, 2, 0, 3, 7, 1}`. I want to transform this into `{0+60+2, 600+20+8, 200+80+2, ...} = {62, 628, 282, 820, 203, 37, 371}` and this is then stored in a sorted set. Please note that I chose base 10 to simplify the problem, actually the base varies (maximum in set plus 1, thus my method would generate a unique ID for each permutation of three numbers from the set).

I've tested three different pieces of code:

1)

```
sums = New SortedSet(Of Integer)()
For i = 0 To integers.Count - 3
  sums.Add(integers(i) * 100 + integers(i + 1) * 10 + integers(i + 2))
Next
```

2)

```
sums = New SortedSet(Of Integer)(
  integers.Take(integers.Count - 2).Select(
    Function(val, index) val * 100 + integers(index + 1) * 10 + integers(index + 2)
  )
)
```

3)

```
Dim num = integers.Count - 2
Dim intsX = integers.Take(num)
Dim intsY = integers.Skip(1).Take(num)
Dim intsZ = integers.Skip(2)
sums = New SortedSet(Of Integer)(
  intsX.Zip(
  intsY, Function(x, y) x * 100 + y * 10).Zip(
  intsZ, Function(xy, z) xy + z)
)
```

All three methods work, but my tests with roughly 62k integer sets showed that there are significant differences in execution time: method 1): 1.8-2 seconds, method 2: 1.4-1.5 seconds, method 3: 0.75-0.77 seconds.

Since performance will be crucial for my project, I'm still not sure if this is the best code to achieve what I want. Does anyone have yet another idea that I could test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with both 1st and 2nd of your attempts is connected to VB.NET way of solving array-like indexer access on `IEnumerable(Of T)`. That kinds of calls are translated into `ElementAtOrDefault()` extension method calls, so your first method looks like that:

```
For i = 0 To integers.Count - 3
  sums.Add(integers.ElementAtOrDefault(i) * 100 + integers.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1) * 10 + integers.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 2))
Next
```

And yes, `ElementAtOrDefault()` may require iteration from the beginning of the collection every time you call it (depends on actual `IEnumerable(Of T)` implementation). So in worse case your solution iterates your collection over and over again and you don't even know about that.

And that's also why `Zip` makes it better. It iterates over your source collection only 3 times, which is much better then previously described case.

***Another possible solution***:

You can try with `Aggregate`:

```
Dim sums = New SortedSet(Of Integer)()
source.Aggregate(
    New List(Of Integer)(3),
    Function(l As List(Of Integer), i As Integer)
        l.Add(i)
        If l.Count = 3 Then
            sums.Add(l(0) * 100 + l(1) * 10 + l(2))
            l.RemoveAt(0)
        End If
        Return l
    End Function,
    Function(l) l)
```

Yes, I used indexer-access syntax, but because it's on helper `List(Of T)` it's really an indexer access, not hidden `IEnumerable.ElementAtOrDefault(index)` call.

Comment: I think I'll stay with the Zip code (hee hee) which is easier to understand than your Aggregate version. Thanks for explaining the reason for the differences in runtime. Meanwhile, I know the internal implementation of LINQ since I've seen some source code from LINQ-alike extensions. Now I understand what happens in the code behind and why the runtimes differ so much.